# What 0a0a0a0a mean here?

Tags: android, ffmpeg, shared-libraries, elf

For a quick context:
I'm trying to run ffmpeg on aarch64 android, and have the following error:

> CANNOT LINK EXECUTABLE "/path/to/ffmpeg":
> "/path/to/libary/libc++_shared.so" has bad ELF magic: 0a0a0a0a

But to me it seems that it has right ELF magic.

First 16 bytes of libc++_shared.so

> 0000000 177   E   L   F 002 001 001  \0  \0  \0  \0  \0  \0  \0  \0
> \0 0000020

or with readelf:

> Magic:   7f 45 4c 46 02 01 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00

What am I missing in your opinion?
**What does 0a0a0a0a mean?** If I can interpret the error message I might find a solution. Thx

Comment: ELF Header:
Magic: 7f 45 4c 46 02 01 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
Class: ELF64
Data: 2's complement, little endian
Version: 1 (current)
OS/ABI: UNIX - System V
ABI Version: 0
Type: DYN (Shared object file)
Machine: AArch64
Version: 0x1
Entry point address: 0x3d140
Start of program headers: 64 (bytes into file)
Start of section headers: 6660576 (bytes into file)
Flags: 0x0
Size of this header: 64 (bytes)
Size of program headers: 56 (bytes)
Number of program headers: 7
Size of section headers: 64 (bytes)
Number of section headers: 34
Section header string table index: 31

Answer (score 1):

**Was missing libaries**:

```
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libm.so]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libc.so]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libdl.so]
```

Will need some time to compile or just get the libaries needed to check if the solution is indeed this. But this seems straight forward.

Still not understand why got 0a0a0a0a as the error message.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).